# slideToggle on multiple items, if one is open close that one before opening the other

Tags: jquery, html

I have this little bit of JS i done, simple stuff i know but wondering what the best way would to be if i expanded one and click on another to expand any that are open that would close before the other one then opened.

JS

```
/* Expand course details */
$('.expandCourse').on('click',function() {
  var courseID = $(this).attr('ID');
  console.log(courseID);
  $("."+courseID).slideToggle();
  return false;
});
```

HTML Example:

```
<a href="#" id="link_1" class"expandCourse">test link 1</a>
<div class="link_1" style="display:none;>content here</div>

<a href="#" id="link_2" class"expandCourse">test link 2</a>
<div class="link_2" style="display:none;>content here</div>

<a href="#" id="link_3" class"expandCourse">test link 3</a>
<div class="link_3" style="display:none;>content here</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

```
$('.expandCourse').on('click',function() {
   $("[class^=link]").not($(this).next()).slideUp();
   $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/znFmc/16/)

In each click it hides all the divs with classname starts with `link` except the div related with current anchor.

**Edit**

```
$('.expandCourse').on('click',function() {
   $("[class^=link]").not($("."+this.id)).slideUp();
  $("."+this.id).slideToggle();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/znFmc/17/)

Comment: I cannot use the .next as the source is a little more than that, i just stripped it down for this example. How would i do based on the JS i done - adding to that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks! sliding is working on that code which is great but the others are not sliding back up, so i need to change the this.id to the class maybe?

Comment: Yea i just checked that, im going to check it out :) thanks for your help - must be something my end with the integration.